# How to insert multiple documents from a collection as an array field in another document - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to insert all the documents in the collection "documents"  to a new document as an array. the new document suppose to look like that:

```
{
id=1,
arr=[all the documents from the collection]
}
```

it tried:

```
   db.results.insert({"id":2,"arr":[]});
   db.documents.find().forEach(function(doc){
      db.results.update(
        { "id": 2 },
        { $push: { "arr": doc } })
   })
```

it doesn't work.
thank you

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Not sure why it didn't work for you. Can you add bit more details please?

Comment: i always get a blank array at the end of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
I needed to add flags:

```
db.results.update({"id": 2}, {$push: {"arr": doc }}, true, false)
```